# Parse JSON file in R with 'non standard format'

Tags: r

I'm trying to turn a 'JSON' file into a Data Frame in R and not having much success.

I've tried using RJSON and RJSONIO but both seem to have the same objection to the format of my data and only return the values between the first set of {}. Here is an example of my data:

```
{"response time":"1075","_p":"99ae8e5f1eb64091c019e57ff0e686d3","_t":1397514301}
{"_n":"searcher","version":"v4","mobile":"No","_p":"1797370","_t":1397514315}
{"month":"April","_n":"shown availability","availability":"unavailable","_t":1397514320}
```

This is exactly how it looks if I open it in Notepad++ - as you can see there are no commas between the }{.

The aim is to turn this into a table with each {} as a row with a column for each type e.g. "_p", "_n", "_t" etc. I understand I can use plyr to deal with the jagged nature of my data.

Any help as  to how to approach this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example of how the data frame should look in R.

Comment: Also, you could add a comma at the end of each of your sample lines with `gsub("\\n", ",\n", x)`.  This just replaces the new line character with a comma then a new line character. Or   
`gsub("}{", "},{", x, fixed = TRUE)` if there is no new line character between the braces.

Comment: Thanks Richard, expanded the question to give a brief summary of the output. How exactly do I incorporate the gsub into the fromJSON function?

Comment: Your json is malformed: there are unbalanced `"`. Note the segment `,"trip "_t":1397514320}` at the very end. Is this part of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text <- '{"response time":"1075","_p":"99ae8e5f1eb64091c019e57ff0e686d3","_t":1397514301}
{"_n":"searcher","version":"v4","mobile":"No","_p":"1797370","_t":1397514315}
{"month":"April","_n":"shown availability","availability":"unavailable","_t":1397514320}'


library(rjson)
json.text <- readLines(textConnection(text))
# parse JSON into named list
json      <- lapply(json.text,fromJSON)
library(plyr)
result <- do.call(rbind.fill,lapply(json,as.data.frame,optional=T))
result
#   response time                               _p         _t                 _n version mobile month availability
# 1          1075 99ae8e5f1eb64091c019e57ff0e686d3 1397514301               <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>         <NA>
# 2          <NA>                          1797370 1397514315           searcher      v4     No  <NA>         <NA>
# 3          <NA>                             <NA> 1397514320 shown availability    <NA>   <NA> April  unavailable
```

Notes:

1. Your json is malformed at the end: `,"trip "_t":1397514320}` will not parse. So if this is your actual text file, I'm not sure what to do with it. In this example, I removed the `"trip`, leaving the last variable as `"_t"`.
2. You need `optional=T` or `as.data.frame(...)` will try to "correct" the column names, in particular by prepending `X` to the ones starting with `_`.

**EDIT** Response to the comment thread.

If your JSON has backslash characters, you can set the `unexpected.escape=...` parameter in the call to `fromJSON(...)`, as in:

```
json      <- lapply(json.text,fromJSON,unexpected.escape="keep")
```

Note however that your file does have to be well-formed JSON - no missing `}` and so on. Otherwise `fromJSON(...)` will fail.

Comment: This looks extremely promising. One thing I can't work out is how to import my data from a file as opposed to text straight into a variable? In this case my file is called "testdata.json". Thanks. (btw you were right to fix the malformed data, my mistake when trying to make it more readable.)

Comment: OK. Getting really close! That doesn't quite work, I think because the readLines() does something slightly weird to the json data. here is a row: [1] "{\"response time\":\"1075\",\"_p\":\"99ae8e5f1eb64091c019e57ff0e686d3\",\"_t\":1397514301},"

Comment: It works for me - run the full code. Those backslashes are put in by R's print function: they are not in the data. You can see this using `print(json.text,quote=FALSE)`.

Comment: I ran the full code and got the error below which is why I tried to print json.text: Error in FUN(c("{\"response time\":\"1075\",\"_p\":\"99ae8e5f1eb64091c019e57ff0e686d3\",\"_t\":1397514301},",  : 
  unexpected escaped character '\3' at pos 10

Comment: As you say, it looks good with `print(json.text,quote=FALSE)`

Comment: REALLY appreciate your help. My email is in my profile, if you dropped me a mail I could send you some of the real data :-)

Comment: Better to upload it somewhere (Dropbox??) and post a link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57632/discussion-between-jacob-and-jlhoward).